# Cannot parse the request - MissingJsonReferenceId : Error while creating NIC using PowerShell Az command

Tags: azure, powershell, devops, nic

I am using below Az `PowerShell` command to create the `NIC` for virtual machine.

```
  # Create a NIC for the web server VM.
  $nicVMweb = New-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location `
    -Name $VmFrontendNICCardName -PublicIpAddress $publicipvm1 `
    -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsgfe -Subnet $virtualNetwork.Subnets[0]
```

> Cannot parse the request. StatusCode: 400 ReasonPhrase: Bad Request ErrorCode: InvalidRequestFormat ErrorMessage: Cannot parse the request. Additional details:     Code: MissingJsonReferenceId     Message: Value for
> | reference id is missing. Path properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.subnet. OperationID : 78525e42-a036-460f-10f9-5b993b7ca5e6

**Issue Resolved by Below PowerShell**

```
$Subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $virtualNetworkName -ResourceGroupName $rgName
$IPconfig = New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name $VmFrontendIpConfigName -PrivateIpAddressVersion IPv4 -PrivateIpAddress "10.0.0.10" -SubnetId $Subnet.Subnets[0].Id
$nicVMweb = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name $VmFrontendNICCardName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -IpConfiguration $IPconfig
```

What is the issue in first command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not reproduce your issue, your first command works fine on my side.

```
$virtualNetwork = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name "<vnet-name>" -ResourceGroupName "<group-name>"
$publicipvm1 = Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -Name joyvm-ip2
$nsgfe = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name joyvm-nsg -ResourceGroupName <group-name>
$nicVMweb = New-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -Location "West US 2" -Name "joyinter" -PublicIpAddress $publicipvm1 -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsgfe -Subnet $virtualNetwork.Subnets[0]
```

[image]

For this issue, it may be related to the version of `Az.Network` module, I use the `3.3.0` version, try to update it to the latest version:

```
Update-Module -Name Az.Network
```